# How can I find the power law parameter of a Student-t distribution in Python?

Tags: python, math, statistics, distribution

I have a list of 3994 daily log-returns `ptf`, and I graphically discovered that a good fit for the data might be a Student-t distribution.[image: distribution]

With python I obtained the parameters using Scipy
`(tdf, mu_t, sigma_t) = stats.t.fit(ptf)`
where, in particular, the degrees of freedom `tdf` are 3.36.
I'm interested in studying the tails behaviour, and I know that the Student-t distribution is a power-law distribution. I then checked it graphically in a log-log plot:

[image: lol-log]

And yes I can see the power-law since there is a linear relation at a certain point. Now, I know that power-law distributions depend on one parameter, say alpha, which is intuitively the slope of the graph in the log-log plot. My question is: in the case of a Student-t how can I find the alpha of the power-law? Does it by any chance coincide with the degrees of freedom of the Student-t?

I checked out the package `powerlaw` but I couldn't figure out how. I did this:

```
results = powerlaw.Fit(ptf)
print(results.alpha)
print(results.power_law.xmin)
```

And the `alpha` I got is 4.23. Is this the alpha I'm looking for? What's the relation with the degrees of freedom of the Student-t?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alpha would be your degrees of freedom + 1, so 4.36 in your case.

The density function of a Student's t-distribution with n degrees of freedom is

f(x) ~ (1 + x^2 / n)^{-(n+1)/2}

In the tails (for large absolute values of x) this is asymptomatically proportional to

x^{-(n+1)}

So the exponent in the power law (your alpha) is n+1.

Comment: Let me get this straight. 'My' $\alpha$ is such that $f_X(x) \propto \frac{1}{|x|^{\alpha + 1}}$. In this case, are you saying that my degrees of freedom `tdf`= 3.36 are my $\alpha$?

Comment: If you used the powerlaw package described in this paper:

http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0085777

it assumes that $f_X(x) \propto \frac{1}{x^{\alpha}}$ - this is the definition for alpha I used: so it would be 4.36, similar to the value you got.

In your definition, it would be 3.36, yes.

If you are mainly interested in the tail behaviour, it may be a better idea to directly fit the power law distribution rather than taking the detour via the student-t?

Comment: yes you're probably right, and I read that paper too. But I'm new to the power law distributions so I was trying to work out what I already new, e.g Student-t. Thank you for your answer